# Объекты первого класса Python - полезные примеры новичку

Tags: python, объекты

В книге Д.Бизли «Python. Подробный справочник» есть такое суждение:

> Тот факт, что все объекты в языке Python являются объектами первого
>   класса, зачастую недооценивается начинающими программистами, тогда как
>   это позволяет писать очень компактные и гибкие программы. Например,
>   предположим, что имеется текстовая строка, такая как
>   “GOOG,100,490.10”, и вам необходимо превратить ее в список полей,
>   попутно выполнив необходимые преобразования типов. Ниже приводится
>   грамотный способ реализации такого преобразования: создается список
>   типов (которые также являются объектами первого класса) и выполняется
>   несколько простых операций по обработке списка:

```
>>> line = "GOOG,100,490.10"
>>> field_types = [str, int, float] 
>>> raw_fields = line.split(',') 
>>> fields = [ty(val) for ty,val in zip(field_types,raw_fields)]  
>>> fields
```

> [‘GOOG’, 100, 490.10000000000002]

A есть ли еще какие полезные "для новичка" примеры использования этой особенности языка Python?

А то кажется, что это больше похоже на источник головоломных ошибок.

Comment: Спрашиваю для описания особенностей языка при преподавании языка.

Comment: Практический пример с функциями: обходим директории и файлы рекурсивно, в зависимости от пути к файлу нужно файл обработать какой-то функцией. Используем кусок пути как ключ в словаре, функцию - значение в словаре.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется в данном контексте можно сделать несколько показательных примеров с функциями, которые можно:

- передавать в качестве аргументов
- возвращать
- сохранять в переменную (как ссылку на функцию)

  ---

Пример:

пусть нам дана двумерная матрица и необходимо найти некоторые характеристики (минимум, максимум и среднее) для каждой строки:

```
In [15]: import random

In [16]: A = [[random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(10)] for _ in range(10)]

In [17]: A
Out[17]:
[[6, 9, 6, 2, 0, 4, 3, 4, 5, 7],
 [2, 6, 6, 0, 8, 8, 6, 5, 2, 5],
 [10, 6, 0, 10, 1, 5, 8, 10, 9, 9],
 [3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 8, 6],
 [5, 10, 8, 7, 8, 3, 0, 5, 0, 8],
 [9, 7, 2, 0, 8, 5, 0, 4, 4, 9],
 [9, 3, 8, 6, 6, 10, 5, 0, 0, 1],
 [7, 3, 2, 4, 5, 0, 0, 9, 0, 10],
 [8, 7, 10, 2, 6, 7, 2, 6, 2, 1],
 [3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 8, 0, 3, 4]]

In [18]: funcs = [min, max, lambda x: sum(x)/len(x)]

In [19]: [[f(lst) for f in funcs] for lst in A]
Out[19]:
[[0, 9, 4.6],
 [0, 8, 4.8],
 [0, 10, 6.8],
 [0, 8, 2.6],
 [0, 10, 5.4],
 [0, 9, 4.8],
 [0, 10, 4.8],
 [0, 10, 4.0],
 [1, 10, 5.1],
 [0, 8, 2.8]]
```

теперь для того, чтобы добавить новые характеристики, например сумму значений в каждой строке, достаточно будет добавить имя функции в список `funcs` - остальной код остается неизменным:

```
In [20]: funcs.append(sum)

In [21]: [[f(lst) for f in funcs] for lst in A]
Out[21]:
[[0, 9, 4.6, 46],
 [0, 8, 4.8, 48],
 [0, 10, 6.8, 68],
 [0, 8, 2.6, 26],
 [0, 10, 5.4, 54],
 [0, 9, 4.8, 48],
 [0, 10, 4.8, 48],
 [0, 10, 4.0, 40],
 [1, 10, 5.1, 51],
 [0, 8, 2.8, 28]]
```

Comment: а с названиями модулей что то практическое из этой области может быть?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, например можно использовать ссылку на функцию из нужного модуля в зависимости от выполнения условий...